# Entity Framework query root of type 'FromSqlQueryRootExpression' wasn't handled by provider code. From xunit test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, xunit

I have a method that calls FromSqlRaw, this works fine when making an API call, but it fails when calling from XUnit test `return await _dbContext.Entity.FromSqlRaw(sqlSelect, parameters).FirstOrDefaultAsync();`

I've setup DbContextOptionsBuilder and used UseInMemoryDatabase instead of quering the database:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("My_database");
            _dbContext = new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
            _entityRepository = new EntityRepository(_dbContext );
            _dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
```

Unit test call:  `var result = await _entityRepository.GetEntityAsync(expectedEntity.EntityID);`
I get:  System.InvalidOperationException : Query root of type 'FromSqlQueryRootExpression' wasn't handled by provider code. This issue happens when using a provider specific method on a different provider where it is not supported. when calling this from xUnit test.

I tried removing .FromSqlRaw(sqlSelect, parameters).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); and just said return await _dbContext.Entity.FirstOrDefaultAsync(); this worked fine. It seems like the issue is with the FromSqlRaw method.

Comment: That would be as expected if you are using provider-specific SQL statements/functions. Swithcing to an in-memory DB is not really any different to changing a connection string to an alternative database provider. Raw SQL containing provider-specific. Statements like FromSQLRaw should be used very sparingly in EF and you will need to test around them, leaving those scenarios to more of an integration-style test against a known state database rather than a unit test.

Comment: There's no workaround?

Comment: The work-around is to exclude that area from unit testing and have it covered with an integration test. The whole point of unit testing is to test business logic which should be independent of data persistence concerns, so unit tests shouldn't even need an in-memory DB but rather mocking out the persistence entirely. To test DAL behaviour for things that happen behind the scenes, that is more suited to integration tests with a real DB. InMemory is not 100% compatible with a real database and should not be relied on entirely for testing.